# double pointers to C++ objects

Tags: c++, double-pointer

I need to modify a really long program that was written by another programmer. Going through his code, you can see double pointers to C++ objects. I don't understand why double pointers are used in this case, I think a single pointer would do the same thing. An example makes it more clear:

```
class A {
...
public:
   static B** b; //why double pointers here?
   ...
}


Class B {
...
public: 
   B(...)
   func1();
   func2();
}
```

We need to have a number of objects from `B` class, let say 5 objects (**not** a 2D array of objects). Once we create `b`, the code never tampers with *b. Only B's functions are called by `b[i]->func1()`. So, since we don't change pointers, I would guess we could do the same thing by defining `static B* b;`. Am I neglecting something?

Comment: Two-star programmers write two stars. Five-star programmers write no stars.

Comment: @Kerrek : Hah, I like that. :-]

Comment: @KerrekSB: Even 5-star programmers need to multiply sometimes.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I imagine there'd be some sort of TMP approach, though, that abstracts that away ;-) (Variadically, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the programmer needed an array of objects of type B or deriving from B (or simply not prevent that capability in future programs)? Because the objects deriving from B can be of different size, you cannot simply put them one after another in an array - hence the additional level of reference.

In C++, if you are using boost library, this behavior can be relatively cleanly achieved by `boost::ptr_vector` or `boost::ptr_array` which will hide the uglyness of double pointers and prevent you from doing other accidental errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a dynamic (raw) array of (raw) pointers, then you'll indeed need a pointer-to-pointer.

Of course, the C++ way would be a vector of smart pointers, or something similar.

It's difficult to say anything more without seeing the complete context.

Comment: yeah exactly, my question is when you don't change the pointers why would you want to have an array of pointers? Why not just having an array of objects?

Comment: @aminfar: One scenario might be if you need an array of objects derived from `B`.  Another scenario might be that `B` has no default constructor.  Another scenario might be that the original programmer didn't really know what they were doing.  It's difficult to say.

Answer (score 2):

On older versions of the Mac OS, these were called handles. They were used so the operating system could re-arrange memory without breaking pointers. (That is, the OS can move your objects around and change the pointers to them, as long as you only keep a pointer to the pointer.)

It's hard to know what's going on in your case, but you might want to check to see if some sort of similar memory optimization is going on.

Comment: interesting! that might be the case, since the guy who wrote the code used a Mac machine. So, since I use Ubuntu, can I get rid of all double pointers w/o sacrificing anything?

Comment: @aminfar: You need to look at the code to figure that out.  You haven't posted the code that actually populates `b`, so we'd just be guessing.

Comment: @aminfar This was on versions of the Mac OS prior to OS X, which has been around 10 years. So, there is probably nothing Mac specific in the code. The issue is that the previous guy might have been using the same _technique_, which is what you have to figure out before you can get rid of the double pointer.

Comment: Previous versions of "Windows" also used "Handles". I use them for a some O.S. applications, usually memory intensive use related

Answer (score 1):

If it was a single pointer then, you're right, it would be a list of pointers to instances of B objects.

The fact that there are double pointers doesn't necessarily mean he was trying to create a 2D array of B objects. Maybe he was trying to make the list of B objects not a list of B objects but a rather a list of references to B objects (e.g. pointers to B objects).

Maybe in the context of your application storing pointers to B objects rather than the objects themselves sounds like a good idea?

Anyway, like I said, double pointers doesn't always mean double lists.

Comment: Yes. He is making a list of pointers to B Objects. But can you explain it a little bit more? I mean in what cases you want to have a list of pointers to objects, rather than a list of objects? The only case that I can think of is where you want to change the pointers. Are there any other reasons?

Comment: I really couldn't say, seeing as how there's not a lot of information about the application at hand, but I can think of at least this: class A has a copy constructor, which is made more efficient if it just reassigns the pointers to a different container rather than making a copy of each B object. This is still computationally linear, but if a B object is very complex and/or an A object holds a lot of B objects, this saves some time.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to something is used to tell code where to find that something or where to put that something. So a pointer to a pointer is used when you need to tell code where to find a pointer or where to put a pointer.